# What is the best way to check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, architecture, compilation, cmake, building

I have to check in CMake script if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit Linux in order to know how to build a C++ program. Which command is the best choice :

- getconf LONG_BIT
- arch
- uname -m

Comment: I voted for the last.

Comment: Being a Linux sysadmin, I have been using `uname -m` for last 10 years...

Answer (score 3):

Using CMake one possible way is to check the [CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html) variable:

```
if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    message (STATUS "Compiling for 64-bit")
endif()
```

Comment: This is good but according to the documentation CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID is fetched by using the compiler, so this would indicate 32bit if you are on a 64-bit and compiling for 32-bits, notably with "-m32".

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to use any two of the methods **together**. (or all three)

Just for the backup, and to be cross platform. Another Linux distribution can use another id strings. Or be it ... FreeBSD.

And just to add another method - check architecture of some binary. 
Like `file /usr/bin/gcc`.